# Eventlet assert exception on queue.put

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, assert, eventlet

I'm getting weird exception from time to time when trying to put in eventlet/queue some item.

```
for message in kafka_consumer:
    queue_in.put(message.value)

packages/eventlet/queue.py", line 265, in put
  assert result is waiter, "Invalid switch into Queue.put: %r" % (result, )
AssertionError: Invalid switch into Queue.put: ([16], [], [])
```

Any idea what could be the reason for it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet that causing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found to this was adding eventlet.sleep() after:

```
queue.put(event)
eventlet.sleep()
```

Hope it will help anyone.